# C++ No way to have a static string

Tags: c++

We are developing software which interfaces to programs written by others which have their own main() and which we cannot modify but we use the dynamic linker to intercept calls to system functions which they use.

This requires us to do things before the other program does.

We therefore must use:

```
/** 
 * Constructor routines are executed before dlopen returns 
 * (or before main() is started if the library is loaded at load time). 
 */
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_initializer(void)

{ (void)new Simple("green");
}
```

Simple is

```
class Simple
{ static std::string name;
  Simple(const char *);
}
----------------------------------------------
Simple::Simple(const char * name_)
{ name = name_;
}
```

Unfortunately this cannot work because at this stage main has not been called and so Simple::name is not initialized and therefore the memory for it is zero.

The only code which can assign to Simple::name is the compiler generated code which has not been called at this point. (This is because the assignment attempts to destroy and therefore free the string and crashes.)

In effect the code running in ((constructor)) cannot refer to static std::string objects.

The term *static initializer fiasco* is used but actually this is a much more simple dilemma than that. Researching this I got the impression that statics are fully initialized at the point where the first method (Simple::Simple ?) is called but this demonstrates that this is not the case.

My understanding is that there is no way to get around this.
Do you know of a way to allow us to have dynamic statics in our classes?

g++ (GCC) 4.8.5

Comment: You haven't: named a platform, told us if your software is the main program and `dlopen`s a 3rd party .so, or is a library `dlopen`ed by a 3rd party program, or if your code and the 3rd party library are _both_ `dlopen`ed by something else, or whether one component has a dynamic link dependency on the other which is being resolved by the runtime linker...

Comment: Your example can easily be made to work by making `name` a const. I guess you "real problem" is not that simple?

Comment: Initialising a static member on construction is a little odd. A function static is the usual solution to initialisation order problems

Comment: The way this is written now, it seems to be a statement. Could you write it as a question? What are you trying to achieve and why. What have you tried so far? What do you expect to happen and what is happening? (And is there a language version requirement?). Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), or even [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: We have no problem with initialization order.  (This example has only one static member and before main is called it has value "") The problem is that we run before main is called but we cannot touch this static member until main is called and by then it is too late.

Comment: We have no problem with initialization order. (This example has only one static member and AFTER main is called it has value "") The problem is that we run before main is called but we cannot touch this static member until main is called and by then it is too late